# subtype & domain from gdb to table (arcgis)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, domains, subtype

We have a **geodatabase** containing an obj class (main table) which has **subtypes** & these contain **domains**.

Need a way (e.g. script) to get those subtypes & domains in a "readable" **table**.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend checking out the X-Ray for ArcCatalog extension created by ESRI.

[X-Ray for ArcCatalog extension for 10.1](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e1e911d7d7374285b1ef03d06b3ee642)

[X-Ray for ArcCatalog extension for 10.2 - 10.3](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ea218ff575f4a5195e01a2cae03a0ae)

---

Here's a snip from the description:

The X-Ray for ArcCatalog add-in can be used to develop, refine and document your geodatabase designs. This version can be used natively in ArcCatalog and replaces tools found previously on ArcScripts.

**X-Ray for ArcCatalog will help you:**

1. Develop and refine geodatabase designs
2. Analyze the differences between two geodatabase designs
3. Merge two different designs in to a new consolidated geodatabase
   design
4. Check for reserved RDBMS field names in your design
5. Replace and reorder fields in a current geodatabase (via GP Script)
6. Import a design with geoprocessing
7. Localize field aliases and descriptions in your geodatabase
8. Populate workspace descriptions for your design
9. Create a data dictionary and diagram for your design

---

And here's a [video](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/1497/introduction-to-x_dash_ray-for-arccatalog) on how to use it.

It's a really nice tool to have.

Comment: This is a great answer and it is a great tool, but one caveat. It requires MS Office, and the specific version they list, and it's different for each version of ArcMap/Xray. In my case, I was on ArcGIS 10.4 and unable to use Xray because it requires Office 2013 or newer at that version of ArcMap, which i don't have. It just gives very cryptic error message without the correct Office version installed.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ESRI tool that will do this for you:

[Domain to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000022000000)

The tool is available at all license levels and is found in the Data Management Toolbox under the 'Domain' group.

[image]

Comment: To create a table from subtypes, you can use arcpy.da.ListSubtypes to get the code and value, but then you'll have to script out creating your own table. There is no SubType to Table tool. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/listsubtypes.htm